# Python capture file parsing

Tags: python

I have a radius capture file, and I need to parse it.  How can I grab individual value pairs and aggregate them.  Here is a quick snippet of the file:

```
Acct-Session-Id = "1234adb"
Acct-Session-Time = 141312
Acct-Input-Octets = 1234123
```

This repeats on and on, continually with same structure but different values.

I need to aggregate the Octets, which is easy since I just do `"if "Acct-Input-Octets" in` structure.

The problem comes in the total will change IF Session-Time goes to 0 (i.e. they re-connect).  Therefore the running total needs to reset, unless it doesn't in which case it is an error (in RADIUS Input-Octets must reset with new Session-ID).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
totals = 0
for line in fileObj:
    name, value = line.split('=')
    if name.strip() == 'Acct-Session-Time' and value.strip() == '0':
        totals = 0
    elif name.strip() == 'Acct-Input-Octets':
        totals += int(value.strip())
```

Comment: thank you, that is closer to where I need to be.  Trouble is that I am trying to get the error, and hence the issue I am having (or maybe its my lack of sleep either or).
However what I am trying to capture is specific error in which the Session-Time resets but the usage doesn't reset to 0.  In other words I have to compare the value pairs and not just reset the total to 0.

Comment: Well, following that example, you could easily remember more values you would need to do your comparisons. *“I am trying to get the error”* – What is the error? Why don’t you show the code you came up with so far, and we’ll try to help you?

Comment: @JacekPerry do you mean that for every Acct-Session-Time that is 0 the next line Acct-Input-Octets should also be 0? otherwise an error should be raised?

Comment: @JacekPerry I updated my answer to raise an exception in that case.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will check it out, on 2 hours of sleep in 3 days so I am a bit out of it ;)

Comment: Sleep is sure nice, thank you Jurgenreza This worked, had to manipulate the list a bit, and such but the problem was the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex approach:

Steps:

1- read times and octets into two lists

2- go over times and store the last index of a '0' element, in the mean time check the same index for octets and make sure if it is also '0', if not throw exception

3- add up the values in octets from the end to the last index of '0'

```
import re

log = open('log.txt').read()

times = re.findall('Acct-Session-Time\s*=\s*(\d+)\s*', log)
octets = re.findall('Acct-Input-Octets\s*=\s*(\d+)\s*', log)

last_zero_index = 0

for i in range(0, len(times)):
    if times[i] == '0':
        last_zero_index = i
        if octets[i] != '0':
            raise Exception('Session time is reset but the usage is not')

totals = 0

for value in octets[-last_zero_index:]:
    totals += int(value)

print(totals)
```